# Android: Once setting the Notification to device gives notification everytime without message when i restart the device?

Tags: android, notifications, android-ndk, android-manifest, push-notification

In my app, i am setting the Notification as like below code:

```
    // for the PAYE 18 APRIL 2011 // 1  
    AM_EM_APRIL_2011 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForEveryMonth.class);
    in1.putExtra("MyMessage","Your PAYE return is DUE on 20th April 2011.");
    PI_EM_APRIL_2011 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, in1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar_PAYE_18_APRIL_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_PAYE_18_APRIL_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar_PAYE_18_APRIL_2011.set(2011, 3, 18,mHour, mMinute, 0);
    AM_EM_APRIL_2011.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_PAYE_18_APRIL_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_EM_APRIL_2011);
```

Broadcast class for notification is:

```
public class AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth extends BroadcastReceiver{
//private Intent intent;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification notification;
public static CharSequence contentText;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // My Notification Code
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;
    //System.out.println("The ID Number is: "+Long.parseLong(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()) );
    contentText = intent.getStringExtra("MyMessage");
    System.out.println("The Message is: "+intent.getStringExtra("MyMessage"));
    CharSequence text = "Your tax amount due period";
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Tax Calculator App";

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    intent = new Intent(context, MenuPageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("twoMonth", "twoMonth");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification = new Notification(icon,text,when);

    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;  // To vibrate the Device

    notification.ledARGB = Color.RED;
    notification.ledOffMS = 300;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID_TWO_MONTH, notification);
}
```

}

All Works good with this code. and i got the Notification. But using this i got notification everytime when ever i restart the device. and there are no any message in that notification. Why it is happend like this???
Please help me for this. or what wrong in my code ???

Thanks.
**Edited**

I have done like this in manifest.xml

```
<!-- To receive the Alarm Notification for two months-->
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth" android:enabled="true">  
         <intent-filter>                 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>             
         </intent-filter>   
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you add a [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) event to your manifest somewhere?

Comment: @THelper: yes i have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth` class specified in your manifest as the receiver of the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast?

If so, then the  `AlarmReceiverNotifictionForTwoMonth.onReceive()` method will be triggered every time the device has booted, and as a result show a notification.

**EDIT:** Your approach with using the AlarmManager is good. The only problem is that alarms are not restored when the device is rebooted. Therefore you need to recreate any existing alarm when the device reboots. My suggestion would be to change your manifest to this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth" android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".RecreateAlarms" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then create a new class

```
public class RecreateAlarms extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // reschedule alarms here
}
```

I don't know your logic when an alarm should be triggered. You may need to save an alarm to a file/database in your AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth method and read it in the RescheduleAlarms to know if there are any alarms to recreate

Comment: Yes i have set the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast. is it causing this ?

Comment: If i remove that from manifest then will my notification works with the desire given time ?

Comment: Ok, I've also updated my answer based on your updated question.

Comment: So will it not notify the alarm on the starting of the device ?

Comment: So for every Alarm i have to create the two class ? One for the broadcast notification and onther to recreate it right ?

Comment: Your first class will be created automatically every time an alarm goes off and then show a notification. But if you schedule an alarm and reboot before it goes off, the alarm is just gone and will never go off. That's where the second class comes in. After every reboot, the RecreateAlarms.onReceive() method is started automatically started. In this method you will have to reschedule the alarms that were already scheduled but didn't go off yet before the reboot.

Comment: If i simple Copy paste the code that i have Written in to the AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth class to the RecreateAlarms class and do as you have tell then will it works fine ?

Comment: Will you also tell me which type of data i have to save in to the database ?

Comment: I have done as you have said but still got that notification whenever i start the device.

Comment: What code do you have now in the onReceive method of the RecreateAlarm class?

Comment: Ok there is no need to update the code. As i have same code as i have in to the AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth class as i have puted in my question.

Comment: Don't just copy **all** code! You need to come up with your own code in the onReceive method of the RecreateAlarms class. Do you understand it's purpose? Do you understand what the code of the AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth does?

Comment: I dont understand what should i have to do in to RecreateAlarm class.

Comment: What would you like your app to do after a reboot?

Comment: Nothing more, just i want is to remain the notification alarm as i have set.

Comment: Ok, and how do you know if there was a notification before the reboot?